# Where is AuthenticationAdminService in WSO2 GREG?

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-governance-registry

I'm using WSO2 Governance and Registry version 4.1.1, I can find wsdl file of `AuthenticationAdminService` in wso2greg-4.1.1-src but I can't find anything by url:

> `https://127.0.0.1:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin?wsdl`

even after I modify `HideAdminServiceWSDLs` tag in `carbon.xml`, while other services like `ResourceAdminService` is available.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restart the sever after modifying the parameter in carbon.xml

```
 <HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>
```

After that you should be able to access the wsdl in (I verified with 4.1.1 server)

`https://localhost:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin?wsdl` or

```
http://localhost:9763/services/AuthenticationAdmin?wsdl
```

Comment: I've got another problem, I login successfully by AuthenticationAdminService, but how can I get an object of ServiceManager then?

Comment: please refer this blog post. http://engwar.com/blog/2013/01/02/using-wso2-greg-api-add-service/

Comment: I've read this in the official document, but if I use WSRegistryServiceClient to get an object of ServiceManager, is that means I login GREG twice? AuthenticationAdminService once and WSRegistryServiceClient once

Comment: Yes. You do not need to login with AuthenticationAdminService. WSRegistryService client uses it internally to login.

Comment: If I don't login with AuthenticationAdminService, can I get sessionCookie? I want to get it because I use ResourceAdminService to get role permission, which I can't find from registry API.

Comment: In that case you can use public WSRegistryServiceClient(String backendServerURL, String cookie) constructor. So first use AuthenticationAdmin and then pass the cookie. Refer following class for details https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/components/registry/org.wso2.carbon.registry.ws.client/4.0.2/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/registry/ws/client/registry/WSRegistryServiceClient.java

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. How can I deploy a axis2 service inside GREG, like AuthenticationAdminService? I've read the source code: org.wso2.carbon.core.services, and found services.xml, but where is this service registered or deployed? I can't find this in activator.

Comment: You cannot deploy services using UI in Greg like wso2 AS.The services available are deployed as OSGi bundles and it is how backend Ui and Sever features communicate.Usually you should not deploy services in GREG and it is AS's job. But if you need to test, you need to install service hosting feature from the P2 repository and deploy through that.

Comment: That means if I want to deploy a service into GREG, I must make a bundle, and put it into GREG. Now I'm confused about how to build such a bundle? In other words, how does wso2 do to deploy a axis2 service in OSGi? Is there some guide things?

Comment: If it is an extension to the GREG current functionality and you need to add a feature you may deploy a service as OSGi would be fine. As i have understood you just need to host a some Axis2 service. For that use WSO2AS and use or install service hosting feature from http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/3.2.0/. Hope you understood the difference